# Android App: how to read Font Size under Settings?

Tags: android, accessibility

I am developing an Android Application and I would like to read the Font Size under **Settings->Display->Font Size**.

So if a user has set his Font Size to Small/Big/Huge, I would like to apply this automaticly to all my text

I am using a Samsung Galaxy Nexus, Android 4.1.2

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Is this in your app settings or device settings?

Comment: float scale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale; Now try it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try reading [`FONT_SCALE` from `android.provider.Settings.System`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#FONT_SCALE).

Comment: thank you for your help. I don't know why I haven't found that :-)

Comment: I just found a simpler way to achive that see also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16558314/995926).

Answer (score 3):

You can also define your text size using "sp" units which is the same like "dp" but scales according to the users system setting for text size. No need to read the font size from the system yourself.

Comment: It may be useful when you have separate layouts for larger texts

Comment: This should be the correct answer for the question, although `FONT_SCALE` was what I was looking for. When creating layouts, you should almost always use `sp` for fonts