# Get font scaling factor to calculate the fontsize

Tags: android, settings, font-size

This question is related to [Android App: how to read Font Size under Settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12987958/995926) I read the answer of [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12987970/995926) which points to use `Settings.System.FONT_SCALE`. So I wrote this few lines:

```
float scale = -66.6f;
try {
    scale = android.provider.Settings.System.getFloat(getContentResolver(),
                                    android.provider.Settings.System.FONT_SCALE);
} catch(SettingNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error: ", e);
}
Toast.makeText(this, "scale=" + scale, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

My problem is that I always get the `SettingNotFoundException` I'm using an Android 4.2.2 device. By the way I that code is in an `onCreate` callback of an `Activity`.

I also googled for that problem and found about 3 sites which uses the same code. Is some special permission required? I tried also the permission `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` without success.

Comment: hmm, I am not sure that you need to read this. Doesn't the system do the scaling for you as long as you use sp units  ??

Comment: Well sure but I have some graphical bugs which I need to fix with that scale factor.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I just found in the source code of [`Settings.System`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) this function:

```
/** @hide */
public static void getConfigurationForUser(ContentResolver cr,
                                       Configuration outConfig, int userHandle) {
    outConfig.fontScale = Settings.System.getFloatForUser(
        cr, FONT_SCALE, outConfig.fontScale, userHandle);
    if (outConfig.fontScale < 0) {
        outConfig.fontScale = 1;
    }
}
```

There is however the `FONT_SCALE` in usage so I checked for that [`Configuration`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) class where the documentation points to `getResources().getConfiguration()`. So I counld fix my code by using:

```
float scale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
```

---

Since my question was about to calculate the correct font size in pixel here is the way I use it nowerdays in Kotlin:

```kotlin
val Number.dpInPx: Int
    get() = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, toFloat(), Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics).toInt()

val Number.spInPx: Int
    get() = TypedValue.applyDimension(
        TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, toFloat(), Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics).toInt()
```

The usage is:

```kotlin
val textSize = 42.spInPx
val padding = 8.dpInPx
```

Answer (score 6):

You can set system font according to font scale.

Example: For huge font scale is 2.0 then you can set as follow.

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.fontScale = 2.0f;
getResources().getConfiguration().setTo(config);
```

Answer (score 2):

Add "float def" param to the end of the

```
public static float getFloat(ContentResolver cr, String name, float def)
```

Example:

```
scale = android.provider.Settings.System.getFloat(getActivity().getContentResolver(),
                                    android.provider.Settings.System.FONT_SCALE, 1f);
```

Answer (score 2):

**2023 answer:**

This is how I get fontScale using Kotlin:

```
val fontScale = resources.configuration.fontScale
```

Comment: Technical not wrong, but the real intent was to get the real pixel dimensions, therefore my `dpInPx` and `spInPx` Kotlin extensions might be more helpful

Answer (score -2):

You could probably use `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity` - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity

Comment: No this is a constant value. On my device it is always `1.33`. I tried that before I found that `FONT_SCALE`.

Comment: What device do you have? Guessing a Nexus 7?

Comment: Yeah the Nexus 7, is that a known bug?

Comment: FontScale is a user setting for availability and has nothing to do with hardware.