# How to programmatically change font settings of Device: font style and font size?

Tags: android, android-fonts

How do we change font type and font size programmatically? I am not referring to changing the font style of a textview or editText.

I want to change the **global font settings**, toggling between font types and font sizes on a button click in my app. I tried checking the **Settings.System** attributes but I could not find them. Any ideas?

Comment: Even if a lot of time passed, did you find a way to change also the font style?

Answer (score 4):

You can change system font using below code

```
Settings.System.putFloat(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.FONT_SCALE, (float) 1.0);
```

and after this give permission in menifest file

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

and then restart your device to show effect..

Note: Its fully applicable for rooted device and in Unrooted device some font may change and some are not.

Comment: How can I make a custom font family of the system by programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`FONT_SCALE` from `android.provider.Settings.System`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#FONT_SCALE).

and also see this.

[Read font size from Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544931/read-font-size-from-settings/16558314#16558314)

Hope this might help you.

Comment: How can I make a custom font family of the system by programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Use the method above, in addition to allowing the app to ask the user for permissions.

Instructions are available here : [Can't get WRITE_SETTINGS permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32083410/cant-get-write-settings-permission)