# Ignore system font size settings

Tags: android, settings, system, font-size

Is it possible to completely ignore system font size settings in your app?

I can only change XML defined widgets to be in "dp", not "sp", but not default android widgets.
I know this is bad practice, unfortunatelly client requires this.

Comment: Could you provide a clearer and wider picture of the specifications?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421676/how-to-programmatically-change-font-settings-font-type-and-font-size change the font on app fore ground and back in app background

Comment: What are "default android widgets"?

Comment: Offtopic: If you know this is a bad practice, try to convince your client not to do this. Noone needs another ugly-looking application, not passing any usability tests, which makes eyes bleed

Comment: Thanks, I thought this would not be possible.