# Change the system display size programmatically Android N

Tags: android, android-settings, android-7.0-nougat

**Background**: Android N comes with a feature to change system `Display Size` from settings, in addition to the previously present feature of changing `Font Size`.

*Change Display Size*:

[image]

*Image Source: pcmag.com*

**Question**:

If an app has `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` permission to change the settings, there are ways to change the system font size programatically as mentioned in [How to programmatically change font settings of Device: font style and font size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23421676/how-to-programmatically-change-font-settings-of-device-font-style-and-font-size). However I couldn't find a way to change the display size programmatically. Is it possible?

**What I've tried?**

I've checked the possible options in the list of [Settings.System](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html) convenience functions provided for changing settings programmatically.

**Update**:

I've opened a feature request for the same here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214124 . If you feel it would be useful please star it.

Answer (score 7):

Just share my approach to tackle this requirement. I achieve this function by using the dirty Java reflection method - although it's not that elegant.

The main reference source code files are:

- ScreenZoomSettings.java (https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/display/ScreenZoomSettings.java)
- DisplayDensityUtils.java (http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SettingsLib/src/com/android/settingslib/display/DisplayDensityUtils.java)
- WindowManagerGlobal.java (http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/WindowManagerGlobal.java)

And, follow the below steps, then you can get the required control:

1. Read `ZoomScreenSettings`.java's onCreate() and commit(). They demonstrate how to correctly get and set the density value into the framework.
2. Read `DisplayDensityUtils`.java. It shows how to use `WindowManagerService` to control the system density. Because we can't get the instance of `DisplayDensityUtils` via reflection, we need to understand which `WindowManagerService` methods are utilized.
3. Use reflection to get `WindowManagerService`'s instance, and write a  `DisplayDensityUtils`-like class into your project.

```
// Where wm is short for window manager
val wmGlobalClz = Class.forName("android.view.WindowManagerGlobal")
val getWmServiceMethod = wmGlobalClz.getDeclaredMethod("getWindowManagerService")
val wmService = getWmServiceMethod.invoke(wmGlobalClz)

val wmInterfaceClz = Class.forName("android.view.IWindowManager")

// Now, we already have the ability to do many things we want.
// For instance, to get the default density value.
val getInitialDisplayDensityMethod = wmInterfaceClz.getDeclaredMethod(
        "getInitialDisplayDensity", 
        Integer.TYPE
)
val defaultDensity = getInitialDisplayDensityMethod.invoke(
        wmService,
        Display.DEFAULT_DISPLAY
) as Int
```

4. Set or get the density value with your `DisplayDensityUtils`-like class. One thing just to mention is that, if you want to pass an index value (e.g., 2 for large display size), please feed it to your `DisplayDensityUtils`-like class's `mValues` array to get the actual density value which is the right one to pass to the framework. Getting the current density index also applies the same concept.

Comment: This requires the permission WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS, and only can be granted by adb :C

Answer (score 5):

In manifest, under application: `android:configChanges="density"`

In an activity/application:

```
public void adjustDisplayScale(Configuration configuration) {
    if (configuration != null) {
        Log.d("TAG", "adjustDisplayScale: " + configuration.densityDpi);
        if(configuration.densityDpi >= 485) //for 6 inch device OR for 538 ppi
            configuration.densityDpi = 500; //decrease "display size" by ~30
        else if(configuration.densityDpi >= 300) //for 5.5 inch device OR for 432 ppi
            configuration.densityDpi = 400; //decrease "display size" by ~30
        else if(configuration.densityDpi >= 100) //for 4 inch device OR for 233 ppi
            configuration.densityDpi = 200; //decrease "display size" by ~30
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.densityDpi * metrics.density;
        this.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
    }
}
```

Call it just after super.onCreate(..):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    adjustDisplayScale( getResources().getConfiguration());
```

This will set the Display Size in-between the "Smaller" and "Small" settings of "Display Size" overriding any Display Size settings set by user.
It **self-adjusts** correctly for 4in, 5.5in, 6in etc devices.. but I'm sure there would a better way than using those if statements.

Answer (score 1):

While referring [Settings.System](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)  , there is a [`putConfiguration(ContentResolver cr, Configuration config)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#putConfiguration(android.content.ContentResolver, android.content.res.Configuration)) method.
Use of this method is:

> Convenience function to write a batch of configuration-related settings from a **Configuration** object.

In [Configuration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html)

> This includes both user-specified configuration options (locale list and scaling) as well as device configurations (such as **input modes**, **screen size** and **screen orientation**).

Set configuration with [SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#screenLayout)  values for screen size.
It is:

> The SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK bits define the overall size of the screen. They may be one of [SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL), [SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL), [SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE), or [SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE).

I hope its helps you.

Comment: @alanv Thanks for looking into it. It doesn't seem like it works. Can you please guide that [Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214124) is the right place to open the feature request for the same or do we need to request it somewhere else?

Thanks pRaNay for the effort to help. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.