# Xamarin Android - Change DisplaySize settings in Android device

Tags: android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on Xamarin.Forms project, in which I wanted to change the "Display Size" in Android Device Settings through code.

I was able to change the "Font Size" using the below code.

```
 Android.Provider.Settings.System.PutFloat(BaseContext.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.System.FontScale, (float)0.82f);
```

However, I am unable to find similar property to change the DisplaySize.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In manifest, under application: android:configChanges="density" .Refer to the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996601/change-the-system-display-size-programatically-android-n

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lucas, I tried with this link, but still not able to change the display settings.