# Android: Can I get the Users Font Size preference Programatically?

Tags: android, layout, font-size, user-preferences

I want to use SP when defining my fonts so that they scale according to my User's needs.  However one screen which I have created looks great when on Normal or Smaller size but wraps text and looks messy on Large size.
So where I have text which has two label/value pairs of information going across the screen, which looked great on Normal, I need to change this to having one pair on each line so that this stops looking messy on Large.
But if I now switch back to Normal or smaller size this does not look so good and not as nicely spaced as before,

So...what I would really like to do is have two layouts, one which I use if the user has a Large+  and a different one for Normal or smaller. To get this to work I need to be able to get the User's currently selected Font Preference.

Can anyone help, I cannot find any reference to how to do this?

Comment: This answer should help;

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544931/read-font-size-from-settings

Comment: Thank you.  The key bit for me is

float scale = getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;

I've tried this and got a value of 1.0 for Normal on my S3 Mini and 1.3 for Large, so I can use a simple > 1.0 test for my changed Layout.