# Design android layouts suitable for large text users

Tags: android, android-layout, accessibility, android-fonts

I'm a visually impaired developer, and I'm trying to figure out how to design good layouts for users that have the largest text enabled on their android devices. I made a good app layout and it looked fine in the designer and the emulator and it looked fine, the tested it on my device with large text on, and everything was incredibly wonky: Text was wrapping onto multiple lines and noting scaled properly. I turn off large text and everything is perfectly fine.

How do I do this? Other apps with large text are fine. What measurement should I be using and what text style/Size is the standard?

Comment: Are you using `sp` for the text sizes? Other than that, I'm not sure what a "best practice" would be

Comment: All you need to do is to talk with your UI disigner :)

Comment: I would love too if I wasn't my own UI designer...Those people are expensive and I'm only 15. I've got an armature web designer, though.

Comment: @Seth Painter: Keep up your good work on S.O.!

Comment: @herbertD 'designer' not 'disigner' :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for standard design principles supported by a strong Case to case study the [Material Design Documentation](https://material.google.com/style/typography.html) is the right place to look at.

[image]

This documentation itself is created by the great minds from Google. All the thing being presented here is the do and don't.

Answer (score 0):

> What measurement should I be using and what text style/Size is the standard?

In general, You need to test the different system font size on different screens to make it looks good, get the font size and test it([Read font size from Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544931/read-font-size-from-settings)). In my practice, use wrap_content instead of fixed height in ViewGroups(LinearLayout), and there is no **standard** style/Size, only the product UI design matters. In some apps like **WeChat** it defined custom app fontSize which will NOT be affected by the system settings, and DO the multi-devices adapt with it's own font system.