# Implementing zoom for all views in app via app settings

Tags: android, layout

I have a following problem. In my App I have to implement a setting-feature that allows the user to set all font sizes and all views in the app bigger or smaller.

Dimensions of all my views are defined in `sp`'s. So if the user goes to System-Settings and changes the FontSize all my views react on this.

Now I have to implement this feature, whithout changing the system settings.

I read this: [android dynamically change style at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241729/android-dynamically-change-style-at-runtime)
and this: [Android: application-wide font-size preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877153/android-application-wide-font-size-preference)

but this can only manage all changes on TextViews and all other Views which are extending TextView like EditText, Buttons...

So my Question is: Is it possible to change the scale factor programmatically, which is used in SP?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more googling I finally found a solution for my problem.
To change the scale factor I'm now using `getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity`

I'm not sure if it works on all devices as it mentioned here: [Read font size from Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544931/read-font-size-from-settings/16558314#16558314)